# What is the replacement for the deprecated TToolServices.RaiseException?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

The Toolintf unit is now deprecated. In ToolsAPI What is the replacement for TToolServices.RaiseException for Delphi XE4?

Comment: What makes you think there's a replacement, or that it needs replacing?

Comment: Toolintf is deprecated. so it need replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are supposed to do the following:

1. Raise an exception derived from `ENonAIRException`, the exception class declared in the `ToolsAPI` unit.
2. Make sure that your code does not handle the exception. In other words let it propagate up the call stack to the IDE code.

The documentation (such as it is, being no more than a comment in the source code) for `ENonAIRException` states:

> `ENonAIRException` exceptions, when unhandled, will not show the user an exception
>       dialog with a stack trace and will not allow the user to submit an Automated
>       Incident Report (AIR) to Quality Central.  Exceptions in IDE addins that are
>       intentionally left unhandled should be of this type (or of a type that is
>       derived from this type)